# Correct Way to analize the time series data where we cant calculate the central tendency

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, feature-scaling

If we are given a dataset of real-time sensors, we need to normalize the features. We might not be calculating the central tendency of the whole data coz it's been updating every 5 secs. So if we calculate the mean with existing data, as the time exceeds we might be getting a higher value and we might get a wrong model.  So which technique do we use here to calculate the normalizing technique? consider it a case of petroleum drilling and we get measurement IN TOTALLY DIFFERENT ranges.

Comment: Why do you think you need to normalize???  Otherwise,< please iclude more details!

Comment: What kjetil said, but also, you can keep track of a rolling mean (or other central measure) and use that?

Comment: What do you mean by "get measurement IN TOTALLY DIFFERENT ranges"?